# Is this integral bounded?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

For some $a>0$, show that the following integral is bounded $$\int_1^\infty \frac{t}{(t-a \log(t))^5}\,\mathrm{d} t.$$

My try:

I know that there exists some $t_o$ such that for all $t>t_o$, $(t-a \log(t))^5>t^4$. Thus we can use this to bound the required integral.

My question:

Is there a way to directly attack the integral provided? Thanks in advance for any help!

Update 1:

It seems when $a>e$, the integral is not bounded.

For any $a>0$, let $n_o=\min\{n:n>a\log n,n>1\}$ what about $$\sum_{n=n_o}^\infty \frac{n}{(n-a \log(n))^5} < \infty?$$

This seems to be true since the root of the denominator is avoided in the summation.

Comment: There has to be other conditions because otherwise that statement is not true. If $a\geq e$, then the denominator has at least one root and the integral diverges by $p$ test.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, how did you conclude from $p$ test?

Comment: Take $a=e$ for example. Then there is only one root at $t=e$. If we were to translate the integrand to $0$, we get $\frac{t+e}{t+e-e\log(t+e)} = \frac{t+e}{t - e\log(1+e^{-1}t)} > \frac{t+e}{\frac{t^2}{2e}} = \frac{2e}{t} + \frac{2e^2}{t^2}$, both of which diverge at $0$ by $p$ test, $p\geq 1$.

Comment: Oh okay, got it. Thanks. Can you check the edited version now? @NinadMunshi

Comment: The updated version only converges if the denominator does not have a root at an integer. You would have to prove that first, since it is certainly not true for all values of $a$, so you still can't conclude anything from $a>0$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, if I change the lower limit of the summation to, say, $n_o$, where $n_o=\min\{n:n>a\log n\}$, then this new series converges because the denominator won't be a $0$, right?

Comment: I get your idea, but it still doesn't work because the min $n$ will always be $n=1$. What you really want is the first number after the last possible root (since there's usually two). In this case the integral will converge, too.

Comment: Did you even graph this function after our responses? Our intuition didn't fall down from the sky, we tried visualizing - which is not beyond your ability if you use wolfram.

Comment: Let's say $n_o=\min\{n:n>a\log n,n>1\}$. How do I find the last root for the denominator? Fifth power is ugly, any methods? @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

For the definite integral there is a problem since there is a discontinuity at a point $t_*$ such that
$$t=a\log(t)\implies t_*=-a W\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function and $t_*$ is a real number.

In the real domain, the integral would converge only if $0 \leq a \lt e$.

What you could use is that, for any $t$, $\log(t) < \sqrt t$ which would give an upper bound at least when $a<1$.

Comment: Oh. Can you read the updated question and say something about it?